# print nested objects with python and __repr__

Tags: python, repr

I'm curious how I should be be implementing the **repr** method of an object that contains other objects that implement **repr**.

For example (pythonish):

```
class Book():
    def__repr__
        return 'author ... isbn'

class Library(): 
    def __repr__:
        me ='['
        for b in books:
            me = me + b.repr()
        me = me + ']'
        return me
```

Do I have to directly call that repr() method? i can't seem to just concat it and have it implicitly convert it to a string.

Comment: There is no such thing as automatic conversion to string in python. You must always expicitly use `str` or `repr` on objects. By the way, in your case I'd do something like: `return "[%s]" % ', '.join(repr(book) for book in books)` instead of those 5 lines.

Comment: Thanks.  This answered my question about implicit string conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `repr()` function on the `Book` instance:

`object.__repr__(self)`<sup>[[docs]](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)</sup>

```
Called by the repr() built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes)
to compute the “official” string representation of an object. [...] The return 
value must be a string object. If a class defines __repr__() but not __str__(),
then __repr__() is also used when an “informal” string representation of 
instances of that class is required.
```

---

```
class Book(object):    
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'I am a book'

class Library(object):    
    def __init__(self,*books):
        self.books = books
    def __repr__(self):
        return ' | '.join(repr(book) for book in self.books)

b1, b2 = Book(), Book()
print Library(b1,b2)

#prints I am a book | I am a book
```

Comment: It should be possible to copy and paste the canonical representation and get the original object that produced it, which I don't think is possible with `|` in the output.  "If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment)."

Comment: @endolith -- You are right, it was more meant as stupid example how the `repr` works, with mild resamblence of a bookshelf, rather than a suggestion how it should be actually implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You want `repr(b)`, not `b.repr`.  `repr` is a function.  `__repr__` is the magic method called on an object when you call `repr` on that object.